# SQL Server result column in WHERE clause

Tags: sql-server

```
SELECT 
   MyColumn = 'something'
FROM table
WHERE MyColumn == 'something'
```

Possible to use `MyColumn` in WHERE clause?

EDIT:

Here's full query:

```
select TOP 10               
    PremiumYTDCurrent=Sum(CASE WHEN 
    AASI.Inv_Acctcur>='201101'
    and AASI.Inv_Acctcur<='201102'
    THEN (AASI.Inv_Premium)*R.[Percent]
    ELSE 0 END),

    PremiumYTDPrevious=Sum(CASE WHEN 
    AASI.Inv_Acctcur>='201001'
    and AASI.Inv_Acctcur<='201002'
    THEN (AASI.Inv_Premium)*R.[Percent]
    ELSE 0 END),  

    R.STAFF, L.Description, L.LINE_OF_BUSINESS

from AAS_Invoice AASI,Invoice I,Revenue_Tracking R,  Policy P, Line_Of_Business L
where I.Invoice_No=convert(Char,Convert(int,AASI.Inv_Entry_Num))
and I.Invoice=R.Invoice
and I.POLICY=P.POLICY
and L.LINE_OF_BUSINESS=P.LINE_OF_BUSINESS
and R.Organization IN (SELECT ST.ORGANIZATION FROM Staff ST WHERE ST.STAFF=14407)
and R.Staff=14407
and R.Activity_type='Broker'
and R.[Percent]>0

and PremiumYTDCurrent != 0

group by R.STAFF, L.Description, L.LINE_OF_BUSINESS
order by PremiumYTDCurrent DESC, PremiumYTDPrevious DESC, average_policy DESC
```

Comment: i dont understand, you can do the above query as long as the MyColumn exists in the database

Comment: That is the point, MyColumn is defined by user, it doesn't exist in db

Comment: If it doesn't exist, you can't use it.

Comment: This is moot, because that query (if it worked) would just return all the rows. What is the context?

Comment: I edited question. This line is essential: "and PremiumYTDCurrent != 0"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not use the column in the where clause. Use the expression instead.

```
and Sum(CASE WHEN 
    AASI.Inv_Acctcur>='201101'
    and AASI.Inv_Acctcur<='201102'
    THEN (AASI.Inv_Premium)*R.[Percent]
    ELSE 0 END) <> 0
```

**Edit 1**
Did not notice the SUM clause.
Try add it as a HAVING clause instead after order by.

```
having Sum(CASE WHEN 
    AASI.Inv_Acctcur>='201101'
    and AASI.Inv_Acctcur<='201102'
    THEN (AASI.Inv_Premium)*R.[Percent]
    ELSE 0 END) != 0
```

Comment: can you please have alook in my related question  please ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13594741/update-sql-server-xml-column-using-xquery

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap the SQL up in a nested statement, a horrendously simple example being, e.g.:

```
SELECT MyMadeUpColumnName, col2, AnotherMadeUpColumn FROM (
    SELECT SUM(sillycolumn) AS 'MyMadeUpColumnName', col2 FROM table GROUP BY col2
) AS t
WHERE t.AnotherMadeUpColumn <> 0
```

Any column names that you (re)define in the derived table become the actual column names for the parent select.